# Como obtener el primar valor igual a otro

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estoy realizando una consulta la cual trae diferentes datos de distintos usuarios, estos usuarios tienen un horario el cual cubre su dia con diferentes turnos los cuales son solo dos, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que hay registros que tienen multiples regristros con casi todos los datos similares solo cambiando la hora de inicio, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de obtener solo el primer registro de los datos que son similares es decir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una imagen la cual me trae todos los registros, entoces estoy buscando la forma de traer solo un dato del parte 1 y 2, es decir solo tomar el dato de la fila 1 y 23, estuve intentado con case para condicionar los datos pero aun asi me trae siempre los mismos datos, este es mi query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Convert(date,CRI.date) as 'Fecha',
    Convert(time(0),t.startTime) as 'Inicio Tabla',
    Convert(time(0),POWS.arriveTime) as 'Fin',
    POWS.code as 'Parte'
FROM 
    [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewRosterItem CRI
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Issue I ON  CRI.issueID = I.issueID 
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Driver D ON CRI.driverID = D.driverID           
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewServiceSummary CSS ON CSS.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWork POW ON POW.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWorkSummary POWS ON POW.pieceOfWorkID = POWS.pieceOfWorkID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Task T ON T.pieceOfWorkID = POW.pieceOfWorkID
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Organization Org on D.organizationID = Org.organizationID
```

Comment: Ya intentaste usar TOP #?? Se coloca en el Select

Comment: si pero me trae solo un valor, lo que necesito es que me de mas de un valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Convert(date,CRI.date) as 'Fecha',
           Convert(time(0),t.startTime) as 'Inicio Tabla',
           Convert(time(0),POWS.arriveTime) as 'Fin',
           POWS.code as 'Parte',
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POWS.code ORDER BY Convert(time(0),t.startTime) ASC) as RN
    FROM [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewRosterItem CRI
    INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Issue I 
           ON  CRI.issueID = I.issueID 
    INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Driver D 
           ON CRI.driverID = D.driverID           
    LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewServiceSummary CSS 
           ON CSS.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
    LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWork POW 
           ON POW.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
    LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWorkSummary POWS 
           ON POW.pieceOfWorkID = POWS.pieceOfWorkID
    LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Task T 
           ON T.pieceOfWorkID = POW.pieceOfWorkID
    INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Organization Org 
           on D.organizationID = Org.organizationID
)
SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Esto: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POWS.code ORDER BY Convert(time(0),t.startTime) ASC) as RN` genera dinámicamente un numerador que se reinicia con cada `POWS.code` y el orden esta dado por `t.startTime`. Usando una "COMMON TABLE EXPRESION" o bien podría ser una simple subconsulta, no quedamos con los primeros valores de cada grupo `RN = 1`. Eventualmente deberás ajustar `PARTITION BY` si hay otro grupo que deba reiniciar el numerado, por ejemplo el usuario.

Comment: muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 *
from
    (
     Tu Consulta 
    ) 
where parte = 1
order by fecha, inicioTabla
union 
select top 1 * 
from
    (
     Tu Consulta 
    )
where parte = 2
order by fecha, inicioTabla
```

Se hacen dos consultas las cuales se van a unir a través del **operador de conjuntos union**.

La primera consulta retorna el primer registro de los que tienen el valor **1** en el **campo parte** y la segunda consulta el primer registro de los que tienen el valor **2** en el **campo parte**.

Donde pongo **"Tú Consulta"** debes pegar tu **Consulta original**.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer lo que quieres es para cada `Fecha` y `Parte` traer el registro con la menor hora (`Inicio Tabla`). Como los demás datos coinciden, podrías agrupar por `Fecha` y `Parte`, y obtener el mínimo valor de `Inicio Tabla` y `Fin` para cada grupo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Convert(date,CRI.date) as 'Fecha',
    Convert(time(0),MIN(t.startTime)) as 'Inicio Tabla',
    Convert(time(0),MIN(POWS.arriveTime)) as 'Fin',
    POWS.code as 'Parte'
FROM 
    [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewRosterItem CRI
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Issue I ON  CRI.issueID = I.issueID 
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Driver D ON CRI.driverID = D.driverID           
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].CrewServiceSummary CSS ON CSS.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWork POW ON POW.crewServiceID = I.crewServiceID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].PieceOfWorkSummary POWS ON POW.pieceOfWorkID = POWS.pieceOfWorkID
        LEFT JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Task T ON T.pieceOfWorkID = POW.pieceOfWorkID
        INNER JOIN [HELIOS\FWPRUEBAS].[FreewayEtib_P].[dbo].Organization Org on D.organizationID = Org.organizationID

GROUP BY CRI.date, POWS.code;
```

No me queda claro si los datos son correctos, o se han duplicado las filas (con la hora de inicio distinta) por algún motivo; en cuyo caso tendrás que analizar que está pasando y realizar las correciones que correspondan.